# UITextView text disappears after applying transform

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I have a simple UITextView with a custom NSLayoutManager in my app. The UITextView have a tap gesture and when you tap on UITextView it animates off the screen. My problem is that when you tap on the UITextView the entire text disappears. After debugging for a while I think it has something to do with NSTextContainer which I pass to the UITextView because If I don't pass it everything works fine. I thought it had to do something with my custom NSLayoutManager but then I tested it with a default NSLayoutManger and it is still giving the same issue.
Can you please tell me what is going wrong? I have attached a sample code for your reference. I have slowed down the animation so can see what is wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpTextView()
    }

    private func setUpTextView() {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.frame.origin.x,
                                          y: view.frame.origin.y + 50
                                         ),
                          size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width,
                                       height: view.frame.height - 50
                                      )
        )
        
        let textView = MyTextView(frame: rect)
        
        textView.backgroundColor = .gray
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        textView.textContainerInset.left = view.frame.width * 0.05
        textView.textContainerInset.right = view.frame.width * 0.05
        textView.textContainerInset.top = view.frame.height * 0.05
        textView.textContainerInset.bottom = view.frame.height * 0.05
        
        let string = "The Ultimate Fighting Championship is an American mixed martial arts promotion company based in Las Vegas, Nevada."
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ])
        
        textView.attributedText = attributedText
        
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = false
        
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }
}
```

MyTextView

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage()
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: frame.size)
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        addGesture()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addGesture() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.frame.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a text view instead of a `UILabel`? Is there a reason you're setting the frame instead of using auto-layout? Is there a reason you're using `CGAffineTransform` instead of animating the text view's frame?

Comment: And... why are you overriding init and doing all of that instead of using the defaults?

Comment: I have tried all the other options. It behave exactly same with auto-layout and text views frame animation. I am using UITextView because I have a custom UILayoutManager subclass where I am overriding some methods to draw glyphs in my UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you are positioning your view "off-screen."

When UIKit generates the animation, it calculates the ***final*** position and decides that, because your text view will no longer be visible, it doesn't need to render the text container content.

If you **want** to continue using transform (although, I'd advise against that and instead use auto-layout), you can fix your disappearing text by animating the textView so 1-point is still inside the view's bounds, and then moving it the final point in the completion block.

Something like this:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.frame.height - 1.0)
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.frame.height)
    })
```

Comment: It behaves the same with auto-layout

Comment: @FE_Tech - yes... I did not mean to imply that auto-layout / constraints would fix the issue. You still need to run the initial animation leaving  1-point, and then finish in the completion. Or... if the frame leaves 1-point of space at the bottom, the text does not disappear: `height: view.frame.height - 51.0` (actually, it seems to fix with just 1/2 point)